# Flutter Geolocator my application does not give me the exact location

Tags: flutter, geolocator

When I press the button to get my location, it sends me the location 5 blocks from my current location

```
Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission();

if (!hasPermission) return;

try {
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  );
  setState(() {
    _currentPosition = position;
  });
  await _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition!);
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.toString());
}
```

}